# Java method for resolving placeholder values against system properties and environmental variables

Tags: java

What is the appropriate, known Java method which helps us to resolve placeholder values such as `${catalina.base}/keystore.jks` against system properties and environmental variables? For example they detect `${catalina.base}` within `${catalina.base}/keystore.jks` value and replace it with the appropriate value.

Comment: Sorry !!! but I didn't get what you are asking?

Comment: Take a look at Typesafe Config https://github.com/typesafehub/config

Comment: What I mean here is whether there is any Java method which enables us to identify placeholder values as above and replace them with the appropriate system property or environmental variable value? For example they detect ${catalina.base} within ${catalina.base}/keystore.jks value and replace it with the appropriate value.

Comment: Note to the close-voters. Just because all the answers all refer to libraries doesn't mean that the question is a soft-rec question. In this case, the OP doesn't ask for library. The behavior could seem standard from a novice POV, and the question is totally legit, but it happens that all of the answers refer to external libraries. This is therefore not a soft-rec question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a good library which supports the intended puprose in [org.apache.commons.lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/package-summary.html). You can use its [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) class for the purposes I have mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not provide built-in method to resolve placeholders.

You have to use some additional code.

## Spring

You can use a PropertyResolver, for example:

- [PropertyResolver.resolvePlaceholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#resolvePlaceholders-java.lang.String-)
  or
- [PropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#resolveRequiredPlaceholders-java.lang.String-)

As an example, the following code will resolve your system properties automatically:

```
String resolvedString = new StandardEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders("${catalina.base}/keystore.jks");
```

Alternatively, if your program uses Spring application context (or plan to use it), you can configure a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to resolve placeholder in configuration files automaticaly.

## typesafehub config

As suggested by @Thilo, this library seem to do what you need.

See https://github.com/typesafehub/config#uses-of-substitutions

## DIY

If you don't need Spring or typesafehub config (both will introduce complexity if you don't need them), I'd recommend that you develop a simple class to do it for you.

IMHO ~10-20 lines of code using regex or even a more basic parser could do the job for a simple case (i.e: without recursive evaluation / dependency resolution).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you read environment variables in Java:

```
    final Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();
    for (Map.Entry entry : envMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }

    final String path = System.getenv("PATH");
    System.out.println("PATH = " + path);

    final String catalinaBase = System.getenv("catalina.base");
```